# Close dynamically added Tab Items using Prism - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, tabcontrol

I'm using Prism `RegionManager`, to register different views with a `TabControl` region inside the `MainView`.

MainView.xaml

```
    <TabControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainViewTabRegion">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel Width="Auto">
                    <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DataContext.CloseTabCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
                            Content="X"
                            Cursor="Hand"
                            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                            Focusable="False"
                            FontFamily="Courier"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Margin="4,0,0,0"
                            FontSize="10"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                            Width="15" Height="15" />

                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DataContext.DataContext.HeaderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" />
                 </DockPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

In MainViewViewModel I'm Adding different views with the same base class.

MainViewViewModel.cs:

```
private void AddProjectView() {
     var view = _container.Resolve<ProjectSettingsView>();
     var dataContext = _container.Resolve<ProjectSettingsViewModel>();
     dataContext.HeaderText = "test header txt";
     view.DataContext = dataContext;
     _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainViewTabRegion", () => view);
}
```

I can add new tab item with the view.

How can I close the tab item, the `<TabControl.ItemTemplate>` in the XAML code above, adds a close button with `CloseCommand` in the `ProjectSettingsViewModel`, with the TabItem bonded to it.

ProjectSettingsViewModel.cs

```
private void OnExecuteCloseCommand(object tabItem) {
     //Close this TabItem
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind the `CommandParameter` property of the `Button` to the `DataContext` of the `TabItem`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DataContext.CloseTabCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
                            Content="X"
                            Cursor="Hand"
                            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                            Focusable="False"
                            FontFamily="Courier"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Margin="4,0,0,0"
                            FontSize="10"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                            Width="15" Height="15" />
```

You could then remove the view like this in the view model:

```
public class ProjectSettingsViewModel
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public ProjectSettingsViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        CloseTabCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnExecuteCloseCommand);
    }

    private void OnExecuteCloseCommand(object tabItem)
    {
        _regionManager.Regions["MainViewTabRegion"].Remove(tabItem);
    }

    public DelegateCommand<object> CloseTabCommand { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to get the reference to your IRegionManager.  Then you get the Region that your view belongs to, and call Remove on the region and pass the tabItem reference to remove it.

Ex:

```
private void OnExecuteCloseCommand(object tabItem) {
     regionManager.Regions["MainViewTabRegion"].Remove(tabItem);
}
```

You can actually just place this in your MainViewViewModel and bind to it in the DataTemplate, then you don't have to rewrite the close command for each tab item's view model.

Answer (score 0):

I cover this in my Pluralsight course "Prism Problems & Solutions: Mastering the Tab Control".  You can see the solution here:  https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/prism-mastering-tabcontrol/table-of-contents

Essentially, you just need to create a TriggerAction that does all the work for you. Simple. Nothing is needed in the VM.

Comment: Is there a link that doesn't require sign up to get to the solution?  I don't think a link requiring him to sign up for a free trial is good form on this site.

Comment: In fact as stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272885/7604843) if you link to a commercial source, it must be either a supplement to an already complete answer, or you should provide the material related to the answer free of charge.

Comment: He wants a free answer, he can get a free trial to get the answer free. If he already has a subscription, its even easier. The answer is there, and if signing up for a trial is too much to ask to get the solution, then he can find the answer somewhere else.

Comment: @BrianLagunas I've took your course, and updated my code. Just want to say thanks. :)