# Is it possible to register View with it's name via regionManager.RequestNavigate to remove it later from region?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In my PRISM-App the user can open a view of a module in a TabView (`Navigate("TestView")`). Now I want to close this view via `OnCloseTab("TestView")` but the registered view has no Name.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel: BindableBase
{
...
    private void Navigate(string uri)
    {
        this.regionManager.RequestNavigate("TabRegion", uri);            
    } 

    private void OnCloseTab(string uri)
    {
        IRegion region = this.regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"];

        object view = region.GetView(uri);
        if (view != null)
        {
            region.Remove(view);
        }

    }
}
```

The Module is registered in my bootstrapper like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
{
    base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

    ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
    Type modulePType = typeof(Module.ProductionData.ProductionDataModule);                          
    moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(Module.ProductionData.ProductionDataModule));            
}
```

It works with:

```
IRegion region = regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"];

object view = region.GetView("TestView");
if (view == null)
{
    view = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Views.TestView>();
    region.Add(view, "TestView");
}
```

But the MainWindowViewModel does not know the about the views of the modules. Is there any way to remove the view, when it has no Name? Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Luke. I found a solution for my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652206/close-dynamically-added-tab-items-using-prism-wpf)

In my `MainWindowView.cs` (XAML) I've added the following:

```
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel Width="Auto">
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.CloseTabCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
    Content="X"
    Cursor="Hand"
    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
    Focusable="False"
    FontFamily="Courier"
    FontWeight="Bold"
    Margin="4,0,0,0"
    FontSize="10"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Width="15" Height="15" />

            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DataContext.DataContext.ViewTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

In my `MainWindowViewModel.cs` I changed my CloseCommand like this:

```
public DelegateCommand<object> CloseTabCommand { get; set; }

public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    this.regionManager = regionManager;

    CloseTabCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnCloseTab);

}
private void OnCloseTab(object tabItem)
{
    var view = ((System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)tabItem).DataContext;
    this.regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"].Remove(view);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `RequestNavigate("TabRegion", uri)` method internally adds the selected view to the region using the following method:

```
IRegionManager Add(object view, string viewName, bool createRegionManagerScope)
```

called with the following parameters:

```
RegionManager.Add(view, null, false);
```

so no name is associated to the navigated view. Therefore, it is not possible to retrieve the view object using the view name/uri.  An alternative approach is to try to match the .net type of the view:

```
object view = region.Views.FirstOrDefault(v => v.GetType() == typeof(yourViewType));
```

If this is not enough you can still add extra properties on your view object and try to retrieve them casting the views into a suitable type.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Luke. I've posted my final solution.